# A morphism $X\to Y$ over $k$ is projective iff its fibers are projective $k$-varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$, $Y$ be $k$-schemes and consider a morphism $f:X\to Y$. Usually we say that $f$ is projective if $f$ factors through a closed immersion $X\to \mathbb{P}_Y^n$ for some $n$.

In a book which mostly uses classical algebraic geometry (Hindry / Silverman's *Diophantine Geometry*) it is said that such a morphism is projective if its fibers are projective varieties.

How can we relate both notions?

Comment: It's very uncommon to get the reverse implication here. See almost the same question at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151198/examples-of-non-projective-morphisms-with-projective-fibres) for some discussion of why.

Comment: Dear @KReiser, it is true that a projective morphism has projective fibers?

Comment: Yes, by a simple base change.